# extract whole number and decimals using C#

Tags: c#

What is the best way to extract the whole value and the decimals?

Ex:

```
16.34
23.41
```

I want to be able to extract `16` and `34`, and `23` and `41`

Comment: look into Substring or Split.

Comment: Split it on spaces and periods and then parse the numbers?  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
decimal test = 16.34;
int i1 = (int)Math.Floor(test);
int i2 = (int)((test - Math.Floor(test)) * 100);
```

Comment: If you do like this i2=0. You have to multiply by 100 before casting to int.

Comment: Good spot.  Thanks - corrected